# Check that only one Textbox is filled in per section before calculating score

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a Userform that will be used to complete audits on employee work with buttons for response Yes, No and N/A. There are corresponding Textboxes for each button. There are 2 sections that are being audited and what I need is to ensure that only one of the Textboxes in each section is filled in - They either Passed, Failed or the section did not apply.

My Textbox names are:
TXTPaymentPass
TXTPaymentFail
TXTPaymentNA
TXTReservePass
TXTReserveFail
TXTReserveNA

The button code is simply(One for each button):

```
Private Sub BTNFPayment_Click()
TXTPaymentFail = "No"
End Sub
```

The code for the calculation step is(it calculates everything but more than one text box can be filled in currently):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Control, nYes As Long, nNo As Long, nNA As Long
nYes = 0
nNo = 0
nNA = 0


For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
        If c.Value = "Yes" Then nYes = nYes + 1
        If c.Value = "No" Then nNo = nNo + 1
        If c.Value = "NA" Then nNA = nNA + 1
    End If
Next c

TXTScore = Format((nYes) / (nYes + nNo + nNA), "Percent")


For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "Textbox" Then
        If c.Value = "" Then na = MsgBox("Please choose Yes, No, or N/A before continuing.", vbOKOnly, "Quarterly Audits")
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Right now I have a bit of code that is checking to make sure that none of the textboxes are blank. Instead, I need to make sure that only One textbox is filled in, in each section (Payment/Reserve) but also that at least one is filled in (form cant be completely blank).

Comment: If the textboxes can only be specific values, and you can only have one of two textboxes filled in, then don't use textboses.  Use OptionButtons instead.  They can be Grouped so that only selection can be made among the "group" of OptionButtons.  Then have your validation check that an option button has been selected per group.

Comment: Ok, can I still update the value of the OptionButtons using the command buttons I have? (My boss wants picture buttons/easy use form lol)

Comment: yes, you can set an OptionButton's value to True to select it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Ok- I added in the OptionButtons and grouped them together. I made them work with my picture buttons and all is well in that area. Now the issue is that I cannot figure out the logic around the calculation piece.
`For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "Optionbutton" Then
        If OBPaymentPass = True Then nYes = nYes + 1
        If OBPaymentFail = True Then nNo = nNo + 1
        If OBPaymentNA = True Then nNA = nNA + 1
    End If
Next c

TXTScore = Format((nYes) / (nYes + nNo + nNA), "Percent")
`
It gets stuck right at the TXTScore section.

Comment: So if there is 1 yes and 1 No that would = 50%. If there is 1 NA and 1 Yes that would = 100%

Comment: `Me.txtscore.value = nYes / (nYes + nNo + nNa) & " percent"`? I'm assuming `TXTScore` is a textbox. Otherwise uf it is a variable you are assigning to something else, try `TXTScore =  nYes / (nYes + nNo + nNa) & " percent"` maybe?